# Can someone help me figure out these tracks genre?

Tags: identify-this-genre, electronic-music

Yo anyone here who could help me put these songs into genres? I have no clue how to even explain what kind of music genre these tracks would be labeled nor are similar to...

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hi Bubba Zubster, and welcome to Stack Exchange. As an FYI, we sometimes get posts just intended to drive traffic to a website or YouTube channel. To avoid the appearance, consider editing your question to clarify your purpose in asking.

Comment: Ty for the answer, its not about promoting my channel, I am just not that experienced when it comes to music theory and understanding. I really do enjoy music and making it of course, but to clarify I just wanted a direction to what kind of music I am producing so I can adjust myself and put an overall label on what I am actually creating in a musical aspect. 

I will defiantly get try to learn more about music in general. This site has a lot of talented people with a lot of knowledge  in the music scene. I shall learn and improve my understanding of music and sounds in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would classify all three as Dark Ambient. For example, here's a compilation:

. And here a list of artists associated with the genre: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dark_ambient_artists.